# how to download excel file from server in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to create excel file and my web site is hosted in IIS 7 Server. I do not want to use Microsoft.Office.Interop or third party licence version tool for this.

I have a scenario to create excel file which are as following:

1. First thing, when user clicks "export excel" button then three xsl file like:

   test1.xlsx, test2.xlsx, test3.xlsx should be created and zipped in one zip
   folder(test) one by one, depending on the logic all three xlsx will contain their
   data.
2. Second thing this zip folder should be downloaded on Clint system or PC.

Please provide me with a better solution or a free version of excel tool to create xsl on server
.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: yes,only microsoft office interop API,but i dont want to use com object.pls let me know if you have any idea about my scenario..

Comment: You want to create an excel file without using excel?  Good luck with that...

Comment: i don't want to use any com object.pls suggest if you know better solution

Comment: Your only option is pure text files, either a raw HTML table that Excel can then parse or comma/tab delimeted file with `.csv` extension. To create actual Excel file you must use some COM or API.

Answer (score 0):

In my ASP.Net applications I use XSLT stylesheet.

```
Response.Clear();
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=filename.xls");
                        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";

                        System.Xml.XmlDocument xslDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
                        xslDoc.Load(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~\\App_Data\\my_xslt_template.xslt"));

                        System.Xml.XmlDocument xmlDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
                        xmlDoc.LoadXml(ValuesDS.GetXml());

                        System.Xml.Xsl.XslTransform xslt = new System.Xml.Xsl.XslTransform();
                        xslt.Load(xslDoc);

                        using (System.IO.StringWriter writer = new System.IO.StringWriter())
                        {
                            xslt.Transform(xmlDoc, null, writer, null);
                            Response.Write(writer.ToString());
                        }
                        Response.End();
```

Comment: If you want to pack this files in ZIP you can use DotNetZip library. It is free. After xslt.Transform you need to use 'using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path))
                                    {
                                        sw.Write(writer.ToString());' not Response.Write